# Unable to retrieve Policies from PC to BC - Guidewire

Tags: guidewire

Whenever i create a policy in PolicyCenter and try to search the same in the Billing center, it is not getting fetched. I am new to Billing center and made sure to do the following steps for the connection between PC to BC in my local setup.

- Modified the urls in suite config.xml
- added a gosu glass in the PCPolicySystemPlugin and made my env as "local" (runs fine for other envs)
- Modified the username and password to su and gw in the PCConfigurationProvider.gs class

Is there anything else that i am missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the billing instruction flow from PC to BC in LOCAL, you need to do some changes in PolicyCenter studio.

I think whatever changes that you mentioned above are done in BillingCenter studio and that is not required in your case. Instead do the below changes in PolicyCenter studio.

1. Open IBillingSystemPlugin.gwp
2. Change the Gosu class from "StandAloneBillingSummaryPlugin.gs" to  "BCBillingSystemPlugin.gs" class
3. Edit suite-config.xml only if the BC LOCAL URL is wrong (mostly it will be correct)
4. Restart the local server
5. After server start, ensure the "BillingSystem" message queue in PC is in "Started" status.
6. Now create a new submission in PolicyCenter. After bind and issuing the submission you can verify the policy in BillingCenter.

I hope this inputs will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. Yes i have already followed the mentioned the following steps before posting the question. I have found the root cause for this issue. Looks like there was a mismatch in the producer code in PC and BC which i sorted out. Now it is working fine :)